# Por que o resultado deste mini programa é 2?

Tags: c, ponteiro

Por que o resultado deste mini programa é 2?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int *P = (int *)malloc(10*sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        P[i] = i*10;
    }
    int *Q = P + 8;
    int *L = Q - 2;
    int result = Q - L;
    printf("O resultado e ... : %d\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: faltam os includes #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

A variável `Q` passa apontar para a posição de memória igual ao endereço de `P`, portanto o começo do *array*, mais um deslocamento de **8** posições segundo a aritmética de ponteiros, então é a posição 8 que tem o valor 80. Destaquei o número que importa aqui.

`L` aponta para essa posição voltando duas posições antes, portanto a **6** que tem o valor 60. Novamente destaquei o número que importa.

Aí em `result` pega a o valor de `Q` que é o valor de `P` mais 8, e o valor de `L` é o valor de `P` mais 6 (`Q - 2)`, por isso podemos ignorar o valor de `P`, no fundo a conta é só 8 menos 6, que dá 2. Só olhando o `Q - 2` já dá para perceber que p i resultado é 2.

No fundo, tirando o fato de entender que é aritmética de ponteiro é matemática pura e simples.

A aritmética de ponteiro é usada para encontrar a posição relativa de algum item em um conjunto de informações, mais notadamente em *arrays*. Então quando soma 1 no ponteiro está deslocando uma posição para o próximo item. O deslocamento sempre vai de acordo com o tamanho do elemento do *array*. A fórmula é sempre `endereco_inicial + posicao_relativa * tamanho_elemento`.

É possível fazer aritmética de ponteiro em dados que não estão em *arrays*, mas não esse deslocamento linear.

Todo esse código não faz muito sentido, começando por alocar memória sem necessidade e depois por fazer uma conta tão sem sentido assim. Pode ser útil para demonstrar aritmética de ponteiro, mas não é um bom exemplo.